# How to choice adapt classes I/O for some data

Tags: java, io

this is my exercise:

Suppose that you need to write data that consists of int, double, boolean, and String values to a file that maintains the format of the original data. For performance reasons, you also want to buffer the data. Which three java.io classes can be chained together to best achieve this result?

A. FileWriter

B. FileOutputStream

C. BufferedOutputStream

D. ObjectOutputStream

E. DirectoryStream

F. PrintWriter

G. PipedOutputStream

The correct answer is: B, C, D.

Why? In my opinion the correct answer is: A, F (because the data are String and int).

I thought that for data like String or int it is better to use classes that process char data (like Writer subclasses).

Thanks a lot!

A.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write "int, double, boolean, and String".

Found this answer:

> Blockquote Since you need to write primitives and String values, the OutputStream classes are appropriate. Therefore, you can eliminate A and F since they are not OutputStreamclasses

Source: https://quizlet.com/358135613/java-ocp-part8-io-and-file-flash-cards/